# grunt compass error "Could not find compass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, gruntjs, compass

im learning how to use grunt, so far all is good, except now that i want combine it with sass and compass, i did add the two libs, sass and compass, but i got the same error for both when i start it for exemple with grunt compass, i get a "could not find 'compass', same with sass, "could not find sass", but both are present in my ruby gems list... any idea ?

```
{
  "name": "Grunt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.12.2",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.4",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.1",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-text-replace": "^0.4.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

here the Gruntfile.js (with only the compass part since even with only that i get the error) :

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({

        /* Task to watch */
        compass: {                  // Task 
            dist: {                   // Target 
              options: {              // Target options 
                sassDir: 'sass',
                cssDir: 'css',
                environment: 'production'
              }
            },
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default',['compass']);

}
```

here a screenshot that maybe can help ? on the left my gems list, right, the error.!

EDIT

so i uninstalled ruby and installed it again, installed all the gems again (sass and compass), uninstalled also the sass and compass lib in grunt then added them again, now i get a different error as in this screenshot :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LB0Y.jpg)

Comment: Please, describe what steps you have taken so far - which libraries/gems you have installed (possibly commands from your CLI). Without this information it's difficult to address the problem

Comment: Ok i updated with more info, is it enough ?

Comment: It's much better! Did you install `sass` (`gem install sass`), and `compass` (`gem install compass`) gems as well?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the answer... i did uninstall again then reinstall ruby (the exe windows installer) but did check the checkbox "Add ruby executables to your PATH", this was the problem ! all good now ! thanks a lot for the help.